# Flutter - Navegação entre telas

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

Eu sou iniciante em flutter e estou com dúvidas em como fazer alternância entre páginas. A seguir um código que eu construí para realizar essa função, mas não deu certo.

```
_buttons(context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            _button(context,"Page 1", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage1())),
            _button(context,"Page 2", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage2())),
            _button(context,"Page 3", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage3())),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            _button(context,"Page 4", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage4())),
            _button(context,"Page 5", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage5())),
            _button(context,"Page 6", () => _onClickNavigator(context, HelloPage6()))
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
 
  _button(BuildContext context, String text, Function onPressed) {
    return ElevatedButton( 
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed : () => onPressed 
        );
  }
  void _onClickNavigator(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return page;
    }));
  }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? As páginas HelloPage (1 a 6) estão retornando apenas um appBar da seguinte maneira:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class HelloPage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const HelloPage1({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text ("Teste 1")), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá. As tuas páginas **HelloPage...** devolvem o Widget `Scaffold` no método build, porém você não definiu o parâmetro nomeado **body** que é justamente o corpo da tua página, trazendo visível somente o `AppBar`, como já notou.

Exemplo de `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Teste 1),
  ),
  body: Center(child: Text('Olá mundo'))
)
```

Abs